# how to get youtube video list and display them in thumbnail

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I need to get a list of videos from a youtube channel, ie http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxnVeUnlga-GKeY2ghGGu_qQkGssuP5HM, and display first 5 videos in a row.

the embed code doesn't allows me to do so. No customize param that allows me to do so...

can anyone advice? an example would be much appreciated!

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Hey but what language are using for android check [this](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/show-youtube-user-videos-in-a-listview/) also check this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/) for guides and tutorials on V3. All the best.